# Aurelia CLI and gulp notifications (Windows)

Tags: gulp, aurelia

How do I disable the gulp toast notifications (Windows 10) when rebuilding my app using the aurelia-cli.  Extremely annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the generated build tasks to remove the notification, which are located in aurelia_project/tasks.  Just change any gulp-plumber calls omitting the configured errorHandler:

```
return eventStream.merge(dts, src)
.pipe(plumber(/*{ errorHandler: notify.onError('Error: <%= error.message %>') }*/))
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(ts(typescriptCompiler))
.pipe(build.bundle());
```

Comment: As pete says and in my case the culprit (driving me insane) was in aurelia_project\tasks\transpile.ts